# Tooltip and annotation both in google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

can we use tool-tip and annotations both in same chart in google bar chart? please share your experiences. thanks

```
            annotations: {
                 textStyle: {
                     color: 'black',
                     fontSize: 11,
                     fontWeight: 'bold',
                     format: 'short',
                 },
                 alwaysOutside: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                isHtml: true,
                trigger: 'selection'
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use both tooltips and annotations in same chart

to do so, you use both [annotation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole) & [tooltip](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole) column roles

in the data table, or data view, add the role after each data column it represents

**data table**

```
X, Y, annotation role, tooltip role
```

in the following example, a data view is used, so the tooltip can be built dynamically

in order to have html tooltips, two things must by in place.

the chart options must include...

```
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
```

and the column role must include a property...

```
    p: {html: true}
```

however, there is a bug in google charts,
column properties are ignored when using a data view,
so we convert the data view to a data table when drawing...

```
  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);  // <-- convert to data table
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Element", "Density"],
    ["Copper", 8.94],
    ["Silver", 10.49],
    ["Gold", 19.30],
    ["Platinum", 21.45]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    calc: 'stringify'
  }, {
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><div><span>' + dt.getValue(row, 0) + '</span></div><div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(1) + ':&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>' + dt.getValue(row, 1) + '</span></div>';
    },
    p: {html: true}
  }]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 11,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
      alwaysOutside: true
    },
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true,
      trigger: 'selection'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat for brief reply.  In my case I am consuming data from api. due to data security I can't share my dataset. In my data set I am getting 'annotation' and 'tooltip' both but not getting property 'P' (which you mentioned in your) i property is mandatory for it?

Comment: Yes, it is required for html tooltips. You use method setColumnProperty after creating the debatable